# How to use Outer Method's input in Anonymous Inner Class?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class, outer-classes

For Instance how can I use the input 'hasTypedSomeToken' in my Anonymou inner class in the following -

```
    public class Login {

        void display(boolean hasTypedSomeToken)
        {
           //some code here

               Button btnLogIn = new Button("Login", new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    if(Login.this.hasTypedSomeToken) //HOW TO USE hasTypedSomeToken HERE 
                    {

                    //do something

                    }
                }
          }
      }
```

Comment: `Login.this.something` is for accessing field of this `Login` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I know it. Just instead of writing hasTypedSomeToken(which is also incorrect) I typed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables declared within a method are local variables. e.g. `hasTypedSomeToken` and `btnLogIn` are local variables in your `display` method.

And if you want to use those variables inside a local inner class (classes that are defined inside a method e.g. the anonymous class that implements `ClickHandler` in your case) then you have to declare them `final`.

e.g.

```
void display(final boolean hasTypedSomeToken) {
```

If you look at `Login.this.hasTypedSomeToken`, `this` is used to access member variables. Local variables are not members of class. They are automatic variables that live only within the method.

Comment: I got 3 superfast answers and 1 elaborated answer in so less time. Im feeling like choosing among one of my own children :( Since this answer has some more explanation attached to it (& Iv to chose one) Im choosing it but thanks to u all equally

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have to make it `final`:

```
void display(final boolean hasTypedSomeToken)
```

Then you can refer to it simply as `hasTypedSomeToken`:

```
if (hasTypedSomeToken) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it `final`, like this `void display(final boolean hasTypedSomeToken)`, and use it without prefixes: `if(hasTypedSomeToken)`.

Answer (score 2):

Make the variable `final`:

```
public class Login {

    void display(final boolean hasTypedSomeToken) {
        Button btnLogIn = new Button("Login", new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                if (hasTypedSomeToken) {
                    // frob a widget
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```